# Solspace Importer: "The following field is required:, The following field is required:"

Tags: channel-entries, solspace-importer, csv

I try to import a CSV with Solspace Importer, but I am unable to do so, because of an unhelpful error message:

> The following field is required:, The following field is required:

Of course i checked the CSV for missing entries for required fields, but I don't seem to have any.

In the required fields of the **channel** I am importing to, there are multiple checkboxes. The data in the CSV for the checkboxes are TRUE or FALSE.

Maybe the error comes from these fields? 
How should I import for checkbox values?

Answer (score 0):

I set the checkboxes to "non required" and I had to make sure the checkboxes can include the values for TRUE and FALSE.